# How to move gun backward when near to wall in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a FPS game in unity. I have wrote a script for gun to move back ward when it is close to a object, And also for enabling gun scope. I have used animation for gun to move back(gunBackward) and to enable scope(Scoper) and also for gun regular position(idleGun). But now in unity when I play the game I am not able to enable scope when Ray hits a collider, The gun starts vibrating. I am only able to enable scope when I look at the sky box.

```
public float distance;
public GameObject origin;
public bool scop;
public Animator anim;
public GameObject CrossHair;
public bool scoped;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2")) {
        scoped = true;
        scop = false;
    } 
    if (Input.GetButtonUp ("Fire2"))
    {
        scoped = false;
        scop = true;
    }
    if (scoped == true) {
        anim.Play ("Scoper");
    }
        if (scoped == false)
    {
        anim.Play("idleGun");

    }

    Vector3 cartPos = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (cartPos+origin.transform.position, transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward), out hit)) 
    {
        distance = hit.distance;
    }
    if (hit.transform == null) {
        distance = 2.1f;
        return;
    }
    if (distance < 2) 
    {
        anim.Play ("gunBackward");
    } 
    if (distance > 2)
    {
        anim.Play("idleGun");
    }
}
```

}